# Check order of rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Need some help with mysql.

I have a table full of bids, i need to check if there are more than 3 bids **from the same user** that are one after another.

Here is some code for example:

```
$all = sql_get('select all bids from bids where auction_id = 1 order by amount asc');
$total = 0;

foreach ($all as $bid) {
  if ($bid->user_id == $user->id) {
    if (++$total <= 3) continue;
    $bid->burned = true;
    sql_store($bid);
    show_error('you cant have more than 4 bids one after another, the last bid was burned.');
  } else {
    $total = 0;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do that in a single query ?

Comment: You are looking for [mysql SUM()](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlsum.php) I guess

Comment: This is the stuff we really don't need to see. What we really DO need to see is your data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id, CASE WHEN @user_id = user_id 
    THEN @rownum := @rownum + 1 
    ELSE ((@user_id := user_id) * 0) + (@rownum := 1) END AS rownum
FROM (  SELECT user_id
        FROM bids, (SELECT @rownum := 0, @user_id := NULL) AS vars
        WHERE auction_id = 1
        ORDER BY created DESC) AS h
HAVING user_id = '{$user->id}' AND rownum >= 3
```

Simply parse user_id into query and you will know if there are **3 in a row**. This asumes that you save the time the rows were created with the `created` column.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do a count query and pass the user_id in the `WHERE` clause?

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(bids) AS total_bids FROM bids WHERE auction_id = 1 AND user_id = '$user->id' ORDER BY amount";
```